# Is it possible to trace the current line in an F# script with FSI library

Tags: f#, read-eval-print-loop, fsi

We are using FSharp compiler service FSI evaluation session to execute a DSL. To be precise we are using F# code to simulate G-Code for a CNC machine. As each line of the FSI script moves the machine to a different location our users would like to see the current line of the script that is executing synced to the position of the machine.

Is it possible to get a callback from the FSI evaluation session indicating the current line being executed?

Comment: Where do you want to see this info? I am picturing a separate window somewhere showing just one line, that line being a line of F# (and possibly the resulting G-Codes).  Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes. On real controllers they show the currently executing bit of G-Code. For my sim I'd like to replicate that.

Comment: ...and just to be clear, on the sim, show both the G-Code (as on real controller) and the F# source?  (I'm not saying I know how to do this btw, just clarifying in case someone else does.)

Comment: Could you do something like replacing every line with `line := __LINE__ ; actual contents` with say a sed script.  That transformation is valid for many bits of F# code.  Then you could just inspect the value of `line`

Comment: It's a long shot, but is this relevant? http://markheath.net/post/linqpad-dump-for-f

Answer (score 0):

Use the **LINE** directive

```
let x = "this is on line " + __LINE__
```

result

```
val x : string = "this is on line 42"
```

Comment: The question was about tracing a running script not finding out the current line from within the script.